# JQuery Mouseleave firing on wrong element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a exit popup to my site using the Jquery mouseleave event as below:

```js
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(document).mouseleave(function () {
        var modal = $(".bd-exit-modal-lg");
        var modalShown = $(modal).attr("data-modal-shown")

        if (modalShown == "false") {
            $(modal).modal('show').fadeIn();
            $(modal).attr("data-modal-shown", "true");
        }
    });
});
```

This all works fine except when I'm clicking through some form fields located in the footer of the document the event is firing causing the popup window to show.

I can't figure out why this is happening as the selector for the exit modal is on the document and not the inputs

Any ideas guys?

Comment: You're attaching `mouseleave` to the document, ofcourse it fires on every element.

Comment: @Teemu, not so it mostly worked however when rapidly clicking the inputs caused the events to trigger. If i did the same thing slowly it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting an upper level `div` around the entirety of the `HTML` so that your `mouseleave` function will have a more specific target:

```
<div id="entire-html-doc">
    your other HTML here
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function ($) {
        $('#entire-html-doc').mouseleave(function () {
            var modal = $(".bd-exit-modal-lg");
            var modalShown = $(modal).attr("data-modal-shown")

            if (modalShown == "false") {
                $(modal).modal('show').fadeIn();
                $(modal).attr("data-modal-shown", "true");
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks very much for the answer, id like to add that adding it to the body tag triggered the exit when using the scroll bar. However adding it to the HTML tag worked a treat